# Access/SQL - split multiple columns to multiple rows based on column ID

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've tried a few things but can't get this to work efficiently.  Help!

Customer dataset example (basically a dump of over 100 sensor board readings with 42 sensors per board)

```
| BoardName | ReadingTime | Sensor1 | Sensor2 | Sensor3 | Sensor4 ... Sensor42      |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| BoardA    | 1224201301  |      18 |      24 |      7  | etc etc for each column   |
| BoardB    | 1224201301  |      18 |      23 |      8  | etc etc for each column   |
| BoardC    | 1224201301  |      17 |      24 |      7  | etc etc for each column   |
| BoardD    | 1224201301  |      16 |      23 |      6  | etc etc for each column   |
| BoardA    | 1224201302  |      18 |      22 |      5  | etc etc for each column   |
| BoardB    | 1224201302  |      18 |      23 |      5  | etc etc for each column   |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

This seems like a pretty inefficient table design.  I'd like to get it into SQL more like the following example, which makes the data a little more accessible.

```
| SensorID | ReadingTime | SensorValue |
----------------------------------------
| BrdASen1 | 1224201301  |          18 |
| BrdASen2 | 1224201301  |          24 |
| BrdASen3 | 1224201301  |           7 |
| BrdBSen1 | 1224201301  |          18 |
| BrdBSen1 | 1224201301  |          23 |
| BrdBSen1 | 1224201301  |           8 |
| etc etc                              |
----------------------------------------
```

So basically, I want to iterate through each row of imported data, split off the 42 columns into individual rows with a 3-column SensorID/Date/Value format.

Comment: By the way, I have a fair amount of MySQL knowledge, at least from the server management and basic query language, I'm a server admin that got thrown into a position of "fix this now since we fired everyone else".

Comment: `|BoardName|SensorId| ReadingTime | SensorValue |`
`-------------------------------------`
`|BoardA   |    1   | 1224201301  |          18 |`

This makes more sense to me.  Thoughts?

Comment: You're right, that would be even better.  I was so focused on the problem of having 42 columns of ID's that I missed that.

Comment: So where does the data for the 42 columns go?  Inline with the BoardName/SensorId table?  Or in a new table?

Comment: I would probably redirect it to a new table.  Until the end user updates their application to better structure the output, I'll be running this query on an hourly schedule to load the data into a new dashboard app they are developing, with it's own database.

Comment: D'oh.  Ok, I see now.  The original table is `Sensor1, Sensor2, ... Sensor42`.  Is that right?

Comment: Exactly - sorry about not being clear on that point, I'm editing the original

Comment: Check out the `UNPIVOT` operator:  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: Ha - that looks almost exactly like what I'm trying to do.  My google-fu apparently is not as strong as I thought.  I'm going to give this a shot in a couple hours and see what happens.

Comment: This is working beautifully - thank you so much.  I'm new to SO so not sure how to mark your comment as an answer though?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use this table structure:

```
|BoardName|SensorId| ReadingTime | SensorValue | 
------------------------------------------------
|BoardA   |    1   | 1224201301  |          18 |
|BoardA   |    2   | 1224201301  |          24 |
```

SensorId values would be from 1 - 42.
To populate the table, you'll need to use the [UNPIVOT operator](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).

Comment: Thank you!  The UNPIVOT function is returning exactly what I want to see.